# jQuery.load without removing <script> elements?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My website is AJAX based and I need to make AJAX request which return sometimes JavaScripts (`<script>` elements). The jQuery documentation says that `$.load` cuts the `<script>` elements because of the `html()` function. How do I keep the scripts and make them run when inserted in the code?

Comment: How are you calling `$.load()`?

Answer (score 0):

[`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) will fetch scripts for you. Just give it the URL of the script to download, and it will (from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)):

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then
>   execute it.

Comment: I need to fetch html and inline JS. It will not help in my case.

Comment: Then change the response to only include HTML, and fetch the scripts separately. You shouldn't really be mixing HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use good old usual `$.ajax()` call and in the `success:` us the `document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = data` function.

edit: didn't test it, but `$("#element").append(data)` should also work.

edit2: document.getElementById("pasteElement").innerHTML = $(data).find("#copyElement")

edit3: now i just tried that idea of mine and i am puzzled, too. im so sorry.

Comment: I tried that: `$(this).append($(response).find(selector).html());`
But the calling of `html()` removes the scripts.
How do I get the HTML without removing the scripts?

Comment: just editted the answer, use innerHtml. If you only need parts of the page, i heard there is a way in jQuery ajax to call "page.html #myelementid" to only get the element, maybe that helps.

Comment: That is exactly the `load()` function, which I tried to use at first. It calls `html()` and removes the scripts.

Comment: im sorry, i answered how to do `$("#element").html("<script></script>");`, guess i didn't properly understand what you where asking for. you can simply do `$(data)` for you problem i guess.